# Match if any line in a piped output begins with a certain character in powershell with Where-Object

Tags: regex, git, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm learning how to use powershell to make a script that operates on git command outputs.

For once scenario, I need to parse `git status --porcelain` and see whether any line begins with a certain group of letters. So far I have:

```
if (git status --porcelain | Where-Object { $_ -match '^\?\?|DD|AU|UD|UA|DU|AA|UU' }) {
       #do work
}
```

The problem is that the output of `git status --porcelain` does not have named columns, so I cannot just access $_. to see whether any of them match the regex supplied.

Is it possible to match the regex on every line, or split the line and match the regex on each? I'm not sure how I should proceed

Comment: FYI, you only anchored the first alternative. You need a group to anchor all: `'^(?:\?\?|DD|AU|UD|UA|DU|AA|UU)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the output of the git command line by line. If any line matches your pattern, set a variable to `1`:

```
$found = 0; 
ForEach($line in $(git status --porcelain)){ if ($line -match '^\?\? |DD|AU|UD|UA|DU|AA|UU') { $found = 1 } }
if ($found) {Write-Host "Found!"}
```

I've added a space between `??` and the filename in your pattern.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I did not need the space and needed to add `^` in the beginning of each `|` and the entire statement fixed my issue :)

Comment: @MLuffy You are welcome. Please don't forget to upvote the answer if you found it useful!